# datepicker using jQuery UI Datepicker 1.8.12 is not showing calender control in IE 10

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI Datepicker 1.8.12 plugin in my application to show calender control to input text box. This textbox showing calender control in IE 8 and working fine. But in IE 10, textbox is not appearing with calender control.

```
$(function () {
    $('#<%= MyDateDateControl.ClientID %>').DatePicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `$().datapicker`, not `$().DataPicker`. There is not such method like `DataPicker`.

Also I create jsfiddle and tested it into browserstack - all [works](http://www.browserstack.com/start#os=Windows&os_version=8&browser=IE&browser_version=10.0+Desktop&zoom_to_fit=true&url=http://jsfiddle.net/RVGJw/&resolution=1024x768&speed=1) fine.

jQuery UI 1.8.12 is old, use more modern (do not forget to update jquery).